# Alternative to java.lang.Runtime.exec() that can execute command lines as a single string?

Tags: java, runtime, runtime.exec

I am calling [java.lang.Runtime.exec(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec) but this seems to accept the command lines as an array and I want to use a single string.

How can I do the same using a single string?

Comment: There is a `Runtime.exec(String command)` method, see your link. And everyone who uses `Runtime.exec(...)` should read this: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html

Comment: @PeterBagyinszki Thank! Now the only problem is that I do want to setup the current directory and still run it as a single command.

Comment: There is a method for that too: `exec(String command, String[] envp, File dir)`

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing not and Java is complaining that it cannot find `python`. The command line executed is something like `python file ....` and envp is `null`, and obviously python is installed (linux) and also in `PATH`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way of calling a system command with a command line as a single string and be able to specify the current directory.

It seems that Java API is missing this basic feature :)

The workaround is to use the array version instead of string.

Answer (score 2):

From the linked Javadocs:

> `envp` - array of strings, each element of which has environment variable settings in the format *name=value*, or `null` if the subprocess should inherit the environment of the current process.

So just pass in `null` for the second parameter, and the environment will be inhereted.

Answer (score 2):

If you pass `null` for the second paramter the current environment will be inherited.

If you want to modify the current environment, you can build it from `System.getEnv()` like this:

```
private static String[] getEnv() {
    Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
    String[] envp = new String[env.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : env.entrySet()) {
        envp[i++] = e.getKey() + "=" + e.getValue();
    }
    return envp;
}
```

**Update**

You can check your Java path with `System.out.println(System.getenv("PATH"));`

If path is ok, then try it with

```
String[] commands = new String[] { "bash", "-c", "python foo/bar.py" };
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands, null, new File("/workingDir"));
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> `envp` - array of strings, each element of which has environment variable settings in the format *name*=*value*, or `null` if the subprocess should inherit the environment of the current process.

It sounds like you want to pass `null` for that argument.